# Runtime differences between using MySQL vs HashMap to store account information in Java app

Tags: java, mysql, hashmap, runtime, difference

I am writing a chat application in Java, and can't seem to find information regarding the runtime differences between using MySQL to store and retrieve account usernames and passwords vs simple traditional data structures, like HashMaps. Very soon, I would like to store messages in this data structure as well, since they will be linked to accounts. Does using MySQL provide any runtime advantages over a natively coded Java structure like a HashMap, or is the overhead constant time of using MySQL not worth it? I will be frequently adding to (~5/500 operations), removing from (~1/500 operations), and accessing (~494/500 operations) the information in the database.

** I am aware of the differences in the persistence of data. That is not what I am asking about and it does not matter at all in this context. I am simply asking what the runtime difference will be while the application is running.

Comment: "What is the difference between bananas and apples"? ;)

Comment: What's the difference between a glacier and a Pina colada?

Comment: Sorry, but your question implies a level of naivety that suggests  that you better spend some real time researching the terms you are so lightly throwning around not having any clue what they are really about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is a database system and a HashMap is a data structure. **They are very different things and have completly different uses.** Databases allow persistent data (data exists after the program ends) and simple data structures only retain their data when the program is running and are cleared when the program ends.

Comment: In the context of this application, it doesn't matter whether the data persists or not. I'm simply asking what the runtime differences are for those 3 operations while the program is running.

Comment: If the data does not need to persist at all, then I would not use a database. Either way, runtime differences between a database and a data structure aren't comparable at all. But if you *were* to compare them for some reason... a hash map would definitely be faster.

Comment: Thank you, that's all I was looking for! (Although I don't understand why they aren't comparable. If they both take a certain amount of time per operation, measurable in the same unit of ms, then why can't they be compared? One must be faster and one must be slower, no?)

Comment: Runtime complexity of a database really depends on the query you perform. Looking up the value in a hashmap is constant time. You're welcome!

Comment: Using an in-memory data structure directly is always faster than using an external data storage solution with some communication protocol involved unless the data structure does have inappropriate runtime complexity for your use cases. In case of HashMap complexity is *O(1)* for add, get and remove - provided that you are overriding and implementing hashCode() correctly for your own classes.